# LTE: How to distinguish three frequencies within one band?

Tags: filter-design, lte

I'm new to learning LTE.
Had some basic queries, I ran over stack exchange couldn't find them because these may be very simple queries but still I'm not able to understand them.

For a particular band of BW say 300Mhz, if we have two frequencies in it say F1 and F2 which are wide apart.
Can my receiver receive at a Freq F3, mid of both with a BW that covers both F1 and F2?
How will I separate them?

Comment: How familiar are you with OFDM? The answer to both your questions is "OFDM", and maybe helping you connect the dots. However, we don't know your background, so it's hard for us to know where to start explaining.

Comment: Hi, I understand about OFDM and read about it. Cleared the first query. Can you guide me with the second? Or where should I focus to understand it.

Comment: well the second is also answered by that; that's literally what OFDM is: dividing a band into subcarriers. your band here is >= 300MHz wide.

Comment: by the way, edited your question: Removed the first query, as you've said you understand it, and changed the title to actually be a title more than a promise for content :)

Comment: Regarding the question your ask now: It's totally not clear what you mean; LTE is OFDM, and your scenario, there's a signal centered around F3 that covers two other signals centered at F1 and F2, *simply does not happen*, that's why there is an **O** in OFDM. So maybe you could elaborate on how/when this happens or how you came to this question?